# Write to File open in Second Function (Python)

Tags: python, function

I currently have the below function within my code:-

```
def openFiles():
    file1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')
    file2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')
```

What I'm hoping to do is now, in a second method is to write to the open file. However, whenever I try to write to the files using for example "file1.write("hello")", an error is returned informing me that `"global variable 'file1' is not defined"`. I've tried declaring 'file1' as a string at the beginning of my code but obviously, as it isn't a string but an object, I'm unsure how to write to it.

Any suggestions? I want a number of functions to have access to the files hence why I'd like a separate function that opens them.

Thanks

**Edited to represent a Class**

```
class TestClass:
    def openFiles():
        file1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')
        file2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')

    def write_to_files():
        ????????
```

Comment: You'll either have to make a class or write to the files within the function you're using to open them.

Comment: Original question edited to contain a class. How would I now reference the object within the class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use python global keyword as shown below.

```
def openFiles():
    global file1
    global file2
    file1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')
    file2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')

def writeFiles():
    file1.write("hello")

openFiles()
writeFiles()
```

However I would recommend you use a class for this instead. For example.

```
class FileOperations:
    def open_files(self):
        self.file1 = open('file1.txt', 'w')
        self.file2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')

    def write_to_files(self):
        self.file1.write("hello")
```

You can then do:

```
>>> fileHandler = FileOperations()
>>> fileHandler.open_files()
>>> fileHandler.write_files()
```

Comment: Original question edited to contain a class. How would I now reference the object within the class?

Comment: how do I call the functions now? When I try to call the open_files function for example, it tells me it takes one argument. I've tried 'self' but that doesn't work. Thanks again

Comment: @thefragileomen declare `x = FileOperations()`, then do `x.open_files()`and `x.write_to_files()`.

Comment: Thanks to the three of you. Appreciated :)

Comment: As a side note, if you are truly opening hard coded files (e.g. the names of the files you are trying to open never change), it might be better to declare the `open_file` and `write_to_file` methods static, and use them from the class itself.